# How to mirror a Linked List in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, mirror

There's an answer out there for Java but looking for something that applies to C++. This code works (kind of) but goes into an infinite loop. Any suggestions are much appreciated!

```
void mirror(ListType & list) {

    ListType listMirror = NULL;
    Node *p = list;

    listMirror = p;
    listMirror->next = NULL;
    Node *q = listMirror;

    while (list->next != NULL){
        p = p->next;
        listMirror = p;
        q = listMirror->next;
        p->next;
        if (p = q)(list->next = NULL);
    }
    list->next = listMirror;
}
```

Comment: Side note: Use nullptr. NULL is outdated.

Comment: Maybe its only me but reading that code is confusing and a pain. What do you think is `p->next;` doing?

Answer (score 0):

```
void mirror(ListType & list) {

    ListType listMirror = NULL;
    Node *p = list;
```

list is of type 'ListType' and p is of type "Node", this is causing undefined behavior (since apparently it compiles) on the while loop.

change this

```
    Node *p = list;
```

to point to the first member of the list

```
Node *p = list.firstMemeber()//this is an example, refer to your documentation
```

Comment: sorry should have mentioned that "ListType" is equivalent to "typedef Node * ListType".